# delete item from listview on clicking an element in it and update listview using mvvm

Tags: listview, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a listview and assigning its source as

```
lvItemSigns.ItemsSource = viewmodel.ItemSignsList;
```

In listview datacell I'm adding button, when it is clicked it should delete the item and the list should update automatically.

In Page:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
  base.OnAppearing();
  InitializeComponent();
  VM = new ItemSignsTabViewModel(this);
  this.BindingContext = VM;
  lvItemSigns.IsGroupingEnabled = true;
  lvItemSigns.HasUnevenRows = true;
  lvItemSigns.ItemsSource = VM.ItemSignsGroupedList;
}
class DataCell : ViewCell
{
  public DataCell()
  {
    var DeleteDuplicateItem = new Button();
    DeleteDuplicateItem.Clicked += Remove_Clicked;
  }
}



private void Remove_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
var button = sender as Button;
var ticketItem = button.BindingContext as TicketItem;
var vm = BindingContext as ItemSignsTabViewModel;

// here vm is always getting null so I had to use an event
vm.RemoveItemCommand.Execute(ticketItem);
}
```

Here in the above code, vm is always null and if I use new instance, my list will not update.

In the View Model:

```
public Command<TicketItem> RemoveItemCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command<TicketItem>((TicketItem) =>
            {
                ItemSignsList.Remove(ItemSignsList.Where(i => i.MobileID == TicketItem.MobileID).Single());
            });
        }
    }
```

So how to get the instance of view model to get my list updated when clicking on the button?

Comment: That should work, although it's a clunky way to do it.  Where are you assigning your page's BindingContext?  Why not just create a class level ViewModel reference instead of casting BindingContext?

Comment: Why would you not bind against the command of the ItemSignsTabViewModel directly? Can you show the view as well?

Comment: I have created a class level view model but could not access it in the data cell. To fix this I implemented an event after the button click and registered that event in viewmodel.

Comment: no. I'm unable to access viewmodel with an item in datacell, so used event on clicking the button

Comment: could you show your complete code of Page ? `lvItemSigns.ItemsSource = viewmodel.ItemSignsList;` here you have generated the viewmodel,could not access ?

Comment: @SaiSunkari   `var vm = BindingContext as ItemSignsTabViewModel;
vm.RemoveItemCommand.Execute(ticketItem);`  change to `VM.RemoveItemCommand.Execute(ticketItem);` could not work ?.

Comment: Yes I tried. Did not work. It says type or namespace "VM" could not be found

Comment: could you show the whole page.xaml.cs?

Answer (score 0):

> VM = new ItemSignsTabViewModel(this);

you have generated the viewmodel,why not use it directly below?

```
DeleteDuplicateItem.Clicked += Remove_Clicked;

private void Remove_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   var button = sender as Button;
   var ticketItem = button.BindingContext as TicketItem;
   VM.RemoveItemCommand.Execute(ticketItem);
 }
```